# Matlab: animation

Tags: matlab, animation

I want to write a program which shows a visual animation of the orbit of satellite in 3D space, with the Earth's rotation.
I can write a code which shows a visualisation of the orbit (simply comet3()). It is possible to rotate the 3D model of the Earth either.
But I can't merge these two programs.
I've seen some Youtube videos like "Satellite Orbit Analysis and Simulation (in MATLAB)". How has he done it?

Is there any special stackexchange site for Matlab questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a demo how to draw the Earth in 3D or 2D here:

[Earth's Topography](http://www.mathworks.com/products/demos/shipping/matlab/earthmap.html)

To rotate an object like surface you can use function [ROTATE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rotate.html). For example:

```
rotate(hsurf, [0 0 1], 20) #% rotates surface with handle hsurf around z axis by 20 deg
```

In addition have a look at [Orbit Determination Toolbox (ODTBX)](http://odtbx.sourceforge.net/).

And yeh, the best MATLAB SE site is here at SO. Just add or search for [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) tag.

---

UPDATE: Another beautiful Earth plot at FileExchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25048

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing the graphical front-end in Java. MATLAB interfaces flawlessly with Java, and it's much easier to do GUI stuff in Java. If you don't know Java and you have time, start learning, it's worth the effort as a general purpose programming language that's everywhere, and it's an invaluable companion to MATLAB.